# Report with combined fields

Tags: reporting-services

I need to create report to render like image below:

[image]

So, for each question, I have several answers (4 or 5 answers), and every question have belonging image.

**DATASET:**

```
QuestionId  QuestionName    Image   AnswerId    AnswerText

1           Question 1      Image   1           Answer 11
1           Question 1      Image   1           Answer 12
1           Question 1      Image   1           Answer 13
1           Question 2      Image   1           Answer 21
1           Question 2      Image   1           Answer 22
1           Question 2      Image   1           Answer 23
1           Question 3      Image   1           Answer 31
1           Question 3      Image   1           Answer 32
1           Question 3      Image   1           Answer 33
```

Comment: What does the dataset that drives this look like.  The arrangement doesn't mean much until we know what structure needs to fit it

Comment: What bit are you having trouble with?  Have you any SSRS experience at all?

Comment: I think you should try it first. And ask help if you run into error. Not that from the start we provide you a step by step solution. Their are bunch of tutorials out there.

Answer (score 1):

To do this I have made the following assumption

- You want each Question Text to appear as a new question with it's own associated answers

I would implement this using a List in SSRS

1. Add a new List item, and set it's DataSetName to your Dataset.  (I have also set the `BorderStyle` to `Solid` in the example below)
2. Right click the Row Header, and select Row Group -> Group Properties, then Group on QuestionName

[image]

3. Within the body of the list item, draw a textbox for the Question name, and Create a Placeholder in it with the value `=Fields!QuestionName.Value`
4. Add a new image box, and set it to use the image `=Fields!Image.Value`
5. Finally add a new table, and set the data to be `=Fields!AnswerText.Value`.  (You may also want to remove the header row)

The final layout should be something like this

[image]

And when run will render as

[image]

Hopefully this is the sort of thing you are after.  If not then let us know to provide further assistance.